# How to parse string value from xlworksheet to time(hh:mm) value into the newsheet?

Tags: c#

I can't convert my object "Time" which has properties in0 and out0 from string to DateTime.

```
for (int row = 2; row <= rw; row++)
                    {
                        for (cCnt = 6; cCnt <= 6; cCnt++)
                        {
                            var in0 = (String)(xlworkSheet.Cells[row, 7] 
                             as Excel.Range).Value;
                            Time.In0 = in0;
                            Console.WriteLine(Time.In0.ToString());
                            DateTime dtnew = DateTime.Parse(in0);

                            Excel.Range formatRange;
                            formatRange = xlNewSheet.Cells[row, 7];
                            formatRange.NumberFormat = "hh:mm";
                            xlNewSheet.Cells[row, 7].Value = Time.In0;

                        }
                    }
 //this is my class
  public class DateandTime 
      {
       public string In0 { get; set; }
       public string Out0 { get; set; }
       public string In1 { get; set; }
       public string Out1 { get; set; }
       public string In2 { get; set; }
       public string Out2 { get; set; }
       public string In3 { get; set; }
       public string Out3 { get; set; }
       public string In4 { get; set; }
       public string Out4 { get; set; }
       public string break_time { get; set; }

         }
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: What's the value of `in0`?

Comment: 0650
0650
0651

0653
(String)

Comment: So you just want to insert a `:`? Or is the new value not a `string`?

Comment: i want to convert all the value inside In0 from string to time format , so i can apply excel formula to the cell to do calculation after.

Comment: Is `xlNewSheet.Cells[row, 7].Value` a `string`?

Comment: yes, it is.  And the error start at " DateTime dtnew = DateTime.Parse(in0);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is that when you use `DateTime.Parse(string)`, the current culture of the thread is used to interpret that date/time. While .NET will assume it is for today if you don't provide a date, the time format is unknown to it: it doesn't know how to interpret a 4 digit number. We have to provide information as to how to interpret this string.

One way you could approach this is to use [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime)'s [`TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8) method, and then format the result:

```
private static bool TryFormatTime(string time, out string formattedTime)
{
    formattedTime = null;
    DateTime parsedDate;
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(time, "HHmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
    {
        return false;
    }

    formattedTime = parsedDate.ToString("HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return true;
}
```

Or you can just handle it as a string manipulation. The following code verifies the length, that all of the characters are digits, and then adds a `:`:

```
private static bool TryFormatTime(string time, out string formattedTime)
{
    formattedTime = null;
    if (time.Length != 4 || !time.All(c => char.IsDigit(c)))
    {
        return false;
    }

    formattedTime = string.Format("{0}:{1}", time.Substring(0, 2), time.Substring(2, 2));
    return true;
}
```

Both of these can be used as follows:

```
if (TryFormatTime("0655", out time))
{
    Console.WriteLine(time);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("bad time");
}
```

[Try them online](https://rextester.com/OZH52516)

Answer (score 0):

`'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'` says the value that you are providing to the `Parse` method is not valid to proceed with the conversion. This means you should look at the possibility of invalid casting happening at the following line:

```
var in0 = (String)(xlworkSheet.Cells[row, 7] as Excel.Range).Value;
```

This could also be true that there exists no explicit casting between the `Value` field to `String` which then can be converted to a valid date format.
For me, it sounds like `Excel.Range` value returns a collection of some type such as an array and there exists no implicit conversion from this array to string, which is convertible to a valid date format.

Update: You may check following urls for the beter understanding of Range and Values.

[Worksheet.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range?view=vsto-2017)

[Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Range_Value_System_Object_)